# How to update coordinates of marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I use Google Maps API and add the markers on the map:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){

var position = {lat : i, lng : i};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
}
```

How I can update coordinates for `marker[i] = 22` if this marker was created before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusth the markers in an array and use setPosition

```
    var markers;
    var k;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){

    var position = {lat : i, lng : i};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true
                    });

    k = markers.push(marker);
                    markers[k-1].addListener('click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
    }

   .....
    var myNewlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 24.397, 40.644);
    markers[22] setPosition(myNewlatlng);
```

Comment: But if I need use ID string instead `k-1`?

Comment: I mean that instead `[k-1]` to use custom unique string key. For example: markers["wyu7hgfn"].addListener('click', function() {});

Comment: When you puhs an element in array you obtain an index (i use the var name k) but you can build a markers array like  prefer  .. if you want you can use also a key index array .. and the use you id  'wyu7hgfn' cor store the related marker